# Normals different from their intended direction

Tags: mesh, normals

I have some mesh who's normals don't seem to correspond to their indicated normal direction:[image]It is just all over the place, and does not change when I recalculate normals. I intended to have the normals calculated inside, to "see" the opposite face when viewed from one side.

Here is what the normals look like:[image]

I happened upon something like this in the past, but redoing the mesh from scratch seemed the only way to deal with the problem. Am I missing something, is there some hidden value that causes this?

Comment: Have you tried separating the interior from the exterior, re-calculating the normals and then joining them back together again? What method did you use to make that? Have you tried using the 'Solidify' modifier on the outer shell? So delete the interior so you just have the outer shell then apply a solidify modifier and go from there? I don't know if there's a specific way that you're trying to make it but just giving some option.

Comment: It's just a single layer, no modifiers, no smooth shading, all normals recalculated inside. As for how i made it, i didn't extrude it, i made circles and patched it together. Does that make the normals all funky?